# PHP Language Server error on VSCode: Connection to server got closed. Server will restart. Language server exited with exit code 255

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using VSCode with the PHP IntelliSense extension (by Felix Becker) for a long time. Recently, an error is taking place every time I start VSCode:

> Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
> Language server exited with exit code 255
> DEBUG     Checking PHPLS_ALLOW_XDEBUG
> DEBUG     The xdebug extension is not loaded

I've already tried re-installing the PHP IntelliSense extension, but it didn't work.

The PHP path is set in the settings as

```
"php.executablePath": "C:\\php\\php.exe"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just uninstall PHP IntelliSense and install PHP Intelephense
PHP IntelliSense has some incompatibility with VS Code

Comment: Worked for me. +1

Answer (score 3):

It's been almost two years since this question, but running `composer update` in the extension folder usually resolves the issue.

```
cd .vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-intellisense-2.3.14/
composer update
```

Comment: Worked for me.+1

Answer (score 1):

Check the PHP IntelliSense settings "php.executablePath" and your environment path, if you're using that.

Comment: worked for me.+1